# LifetimeControllerMiddleware analog from aiogram2 to aiogram3

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, aiogram

In aiogram2 I have the code:

```
class DatabaseMiddleware(LifetimeControllerMiddleware):
    def __init__(self, async_session_maker):
        super().__init__()
        self.async_session_maker = async_session_maker

    async def pre_process(self, obj, data, *args):
        session: AsyncSession = self.async_session_maker()
        data["session"] = session
        data["repo"] = Repo(session=session)

    async def post_process(self, obj, data, *args):
        del data["repo"]
        session: AsyncSession = data.get("session")
        await session.close()
```

But there is no LifetimeControllerMiddleware in aiogram3, how do I replace LifetimeControllerMiddleware in aiogram3?

```
class DatabaseMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):

    def __init__(self, async_session_maker):
        super().__init__()
        self.async_session_maker = async_session_maker

    async def __call__(
                self,
                handler: Callable[[TelegramObject, Dict[str, Any]], Awaitable[Any]],
                event: TelegramObject,
                data: Dict[str, Any]
            ) -> Any:

            session: AsyncSession = self.async_session_maker()
            data["session"] = session
            data["repo"] = Repo(session=session)
            return await handler(event, data)
```

Error:

SAWarning: The garbage collector is trying to clean up non-checked-in connection <AdaptedConnection <asyncpg.connection.Connection object at 0x000001ACE7450C80>>, which will be terminated.  Please ensure that SQLAlchemy pooled connections are returned to the pool explicitly, either by calling `close()` or by using appropriate context managers to manage their lifecycle.
schema = self._schema_type_to_method[schema['type']](schema.copy(), f)
ERROR:sqlalchemy.pool.impl.QueuePool:The garbage collector is trying to clean up non-checked-in connection <AdaptedConnection <asyncpg.connection.Connection object at 0x000001ACE613F060>>, which will be terminated.  Please ensure that SQLAlchemy pooled connections are returned to the pool explicitly, either by calling `close()` or by using appropriate context managers to manage their lifecycle.